# Issue with variable reference not being set in another function

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Hi I am having trouble understanding why after the function call to `changeAdBreak()`, the value of "played" is still "false".

In each of the functions, I've used a reference parameter to be able to modify the object created inside of the main() function.

However, when this object is passed into the function, the "played" property does not get set for some reason.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Video{
    public:
        bool played;
};

class AllVideos{
    public:
        vector<Video> ads;
};

void changeAd(Video& ad)
{
    ad.played = true;
}

void changeAdBreak(AllVideos& mybreak)
{
    changeAd(mybreak.ads[0]);
}

int main()
{
   AllVideos mybreak;
   Video my_ad;
   my_ad.played = false;

   mybreak.ads.push_back(my_ad);
   vector<AllVideos> breaks;
   breaks.push_back(mybreak);

   cout << "ad played = " << breaks[0].ads[0].played << endl;
   changeAdBreak(mybreak);
   cout << "ad played = " << breaks[0].ads[0].played << endl;

   return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push_back` will create copies, so when you do `breaks.push_back(mybreak);`, the element that will be inserted into `breaks` is a different one than `mybreak`.

Calling `changeAd` or `changeBreak` on the original objects won't change the values that were inserted in the respective containers.

Answer (score 1):

Vector breaks defined as

```
vector<AllVideos> breaks;
```

after this statement

```
breaks.push_back(mybreak);
```

contain a `copy` of object mybreak. So now you have two objects of type AllVideos: one with name mybreak and the other in vector breaks. They occupy different memory.

Calling function changeAdBreak

```
changeAdBreak(mybreak);
```

you changed object mybreak but the object in vector breaks was unchanged and you outputed its data member played

```
   cout << "ad played = " << breaks[0].ads[0].played << endl;
```

that of course contains its unchanged value.

To be sure in this add one more statement and compare their outputs

```
   cout << "ad played = " << breaks[0].ads[0].played << endl;
   cout << "ad played = " << mybreak.ads[0].played << endl;
```

To change the object in the vector breaks you should call function changeAdBreak as

```
changeAdBreak( breaks[0] );
```